# If you work at a university and take courses, is the degree the same?

Tags: cv, coursework, administration

I know someone who works at a university and is considering taking courses there (which the university allows and subsidizes for its employees). If they take enough courses to make up a masters degree, will they be accredited a masters degree? Will employees, schools, etc. See this as the same as if they had just done the masters program regularly?

EDIT: In this case, their work isn't directly related to the MS program. Instead they work more generally for the university, in a capacity that isn't related to any particular department. They also hold a bachelors of science in the given field so I don't think prerequisites would be an issue.

Comment: Almost always yes in my experience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many master's degrees have other components besides required coursework, e.g. "comprehensive" exams, projects, a thesis.  Certainly to get a master's degree you need to fulfill all the requirements.

Someone who is taking master's level courses piecemeal should check to see whether and in what way they can fulfill these additional requirements.  This may depend on the details of the enrollment.  However, in most cases that I know about, the department and the faculty won't care much about the administrative fine print, so long as the student is doing well in the courses and shows herself capable of doing whatever extra work is required.

If you do fulfill all the requirements of a master's degree, then you get a master's degree.  Whether you were employed by the university at the time has nothing to do with the degree and probably would not show up on the transcript.  By the way, in many academic fields most or all graduate students are employed by the university in one manner or another -- e.g. as a PhD student, I taught every other semester, and every semester that I was teaching I received a separate ID card listing me as an **officer** of the university.  I had quite a few of these cards by the time I graduated.

**Added**: In order to get a degree, you need to be enrolled in the program. There is such a thing as a "non-degree student"; you might want to look that up. What I and Bill Barth are saying is that, in practice, a non-degree student who is doing well in the coursework and shows herself able to complete all the requirements of the degree has a good shot at getting enrolled in the degree program.

Comment: Do you think it will matter that the employee/student didn't have to get accepted into the program via the usual admission process?

Comment: @Nate: I don't know.  The more I think about it, the more unsure I am about the situation the OP is asking about.  For most graduate courses you need to have prerequisites or need to have the instructor's permission.  If the OP means that by virtue of his friend being an employee he can literally walk in and take any course in the university no questions asked, then it becomes less clear.   Certainly the right to take courses is not the same as the right to enroll in a degree program.  Nevertheless, anyone who shows up, takes a few courses and does well at them has a good case.

Comment: My understanding is that they can generally take courses offered at the university at any level given that their past credentials satisfy the prerequisites even though they are not in any way enrolled in a specific program.

Comment: @user73236: In order to get a degree, you need to be enrolled in the program.  There is such a thing as a "non-degree student"; you might want to look that up.  What I and Bill Barth are saying is that, in practice, a non-degree student who is doing well in the coursework and shows herself able to complete all the requirements of the degree has a good shot at getting enrolled in the degree program.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think you should incorporate the non-degree student info into your answer. That was my first thought when I saw this Q  yesterday, but wasn't in a position to write an answer at the time.

Comment: @mkennedy: Sounds good.

Answer (score 4):

Basically it depends on whether they are formally enrolled in the subjects or just attending.

I think you mean they would be enrolled (since the university is subsidising, this suggests they would otherwise pay full fees). As long as they pass all the courses, do an approved structure (that is, all compulsory subjects and the correct number of elective) then, yes, they get the same degree as any other student.

If they are just attending lectures and doing some (or even all) the coursework, but never actually enrol, then they are not a student and will not get the degree.

Answer (score 1):

Great answers above. One extra remark:  One might also look at the school in which they are enrolled for these degree credits. During my PhD, I had a friend that was working at the university taking all the necessary credits for a certain scientific Masters degree. When it was almost done and he went in for a graduation check, they told him the degree he was going to get was a Masters in Liberal Arts instead of the MSc because he was enrolled in the Liberal and Professional Studies College part of the university (the name for the Continuing Graduate Studies college for the university) instead of the Graduate School of Arts and Sciences. There was no way for the college he was in to bestow him a degree from the Graduate School even though he had taken all the appropriate courses.  Making sure one is enrolled in the right part of the university to obtain the degree is important if one is employed in a large university.

Answer (score 0):

> If they take enough courses to make up a masters degree, will they be
>   accredited a masters degree? Will employees, schools, etc. See this as
>   the same as if they had just done the masters program regularly?

I have never heard of this happening.  Taking courses that make up the same courses required in a Masters program is different than being in a Masters program.  As Peter L. Clark points out, there are more requirements than taking classes to a Masters program.

Put another way, a student admitted into the history department at a university is allowed to take classes outside their department.  Imagine they extend their degree program by a factor of 2, or some other method for taking enormous course loads.  Now they take every class that is required of a computer science degree.  In the end, they do not get a computer science degree, they get a history degree.

Yes, many universities allow employees to take classes.  This is different than being in a degree program which may have a variety of requirements in order to graduate, such as internships, weekly faculty advisor meetings, thesis project, independent work, etc.

As one reference, Cornell has a specific [employee programme](https://www.hr.cornell.edu/benefits/education/edp.html) for doing just what you are asking about.  It also states:

> You must apply to and be accepted by a school or college as a regular
>   degree candidate, as special student status is not a consideration.
>   Prior to the application process, you will need to have the
>   endorsement of your immediate supervisor, your supervisor’s manager,
>   and the dean or executive officer.

This is different than employees taking classes, which is referred to as [extramural studies](https://www.hr.cornell.edu/benefits/education/extramural.html).

Comment: "Put another way, a student admitted into the history department at a university is allowed to take classes outside their department." It is not clear where in the academic world we should be talking about, but in the US undergraduate students are not admitted to specific departments but rather to much larger "schools"; typically one of them is the "school of arts and sciences".  At most American universities I know of, indeed a student who took all the classes for history and CS could get both listed on their degree.  (It would probably be one degree for the same reasons as above.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I am not aware of too many programs in which the College of History and College of Engineering are the same.  Either way, what it sounds like is a double major, in which I have not heard of a student just getting a degree, but rather filling out an application of a Double Major intention http://web.mit.edu/registrar/subjects/cmtes/coc/petitions_doublemajor.html  .  When the degree is not in the same college, much more work is needed, which is more akin to the situation of the OP (not being admitted into a specific college for a degree program)

Comment: Just one more reference of majoring in another department is not as simple as completing the courses and saying 'im done, wheres my degree' http://ls-advise.berkeley.edu/major/double.html

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is.  In particular, who claimed what you have quoted?  Of course if you want to get a degree from a university you have to satisfy all the requirements of that degree and fill out the paperwork.  Your link doesn't say more than that.  (Some of what you said above about colleges is not really accurate at most American universities -- in particular, I don't know any American university that has a College of History, and in the majority of American universities CS is part of the college of arts and sciences -- but that seems to be beside the point.)

Comment: The point is that solely taking courses is independent of a degree granting program.  Just because all of the courses have been taken does not grant a degree.  The OP asked: "If they take enough courses to make up a masters degree, will they be accredited a masters degree?"  the answer is no, just as the answer to a student taking courses outside their department does not just get a degree by taking courses, they need to apply.

Comment: I agree completely.